# if $f = \sin^2x$ and $g = \cos^2 x$, which of the following lie in the space spanned by $f$ and $g$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

a) $\cos (2x)$
b) $3 + x^2$
c) 1
d) $\sin x$
e) $0$

I know the answers in the back of the book state that a, c, and e lie in the space spanned by $f$ and $g$.
I can see how they got a) and c) through the $\cos^2 \pm \sin^2x$ identity.
Is e) just the trivial solution? $0(\cos^2x)+0(\sin^2x) = 0$
Or is something else happening here?

Comment: $0$ lies in *every* vector space of functions.

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks @amd.

Comment: @amd. ... **and** it's the trivial linear combination $0(\cos^2 x) + 0(\sin^2 x)$ and Bucephalus wrote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding of $e$ is correct.

To see that $b$ is not a solution, note that $3+x^2$ is not periodic and not a constant.

Edit:

We can consider another basis of $\operatorname{span} \{ f,g\},$

Note that $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ and $\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = \cos (2x)$

and we can check that they are linearly independent.

Hence functions in  $\operatorname{span} \{ f,g\}$ can be written in the form of $A+B\cos(2x)$. Explaining why the function has to be constaint or the period is $\pi.$

Credit: Carmeister to pointing out another correct solution.

Comment: Similarly, you can see that d is not a solution because it has period $2\pi$, while both $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$ have period $\pi$.

Comment: ... therefore, any nonzero linear combination of $f$ and $g$ must also have period $\pi$

Comment: @Carmeister thanks, I totally miss out  another solution. I thought it is a $5$ choose $1$ question and stopped at the first available solution.

Comment: Hi @SiongThyeGoh, I can see that b is not periodic. Why is not being a constant relevant though. Is a) not a constant too? So when we defining vector spaces with trig identities, the space may have the characteristic that all the functions have the same period?

Comment: Are you saying that b) is not bounded like the a), c) and e)?

Comment: @Bucephalus Since $1=\cos^2x+\sin^2x$, we deduce that every constant function is in the span of $f$ and $g$. Indeed, $a=a\cos^2x+a\sin^2x$,

Comment: Maybe I have to go and look up "constant function".

Comment: Oh yeah, i just looked it up. Thankyou.A function whose output value is the same for every input value. Cheers @All

Comment: @Bucephalus Yes, b being unbounded is also a valid reason.